# Handling "illegal data type (Float64)" error when trying to convert .tif to .bil?

Tags: qgis, dem

Each time I try to convert (in QGIS 2.2) an elevation model from .tif to .bil format a get this error:

> ERROR 1: Attempt to create ESRI .hdr labelled dataset with an illegal 
>   data type (Float64).

The same error occurs when I use the clipper with .bil as output file format.

What does the error message mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the gdal driver (used by QGIS) supports  eight, sixteen and thirty-two bit integer raster data types as well as 32 bit floating points for conversion to bil.

based on the error message, your tiff data seems to be 64 bit (double) type, which is not supported. You could try to change the pixel depth before converting to .bil

Comment: With 16bit it works fine!

P.S.: Pixel depth can be changed via gdalwarp or gdal_translate using the -ot parameter, e.g. "-ot Int16"